# Reference for incremental sandwich covariance from biglm?

Tags: references, covariance-matrix, large-data, sandwich

I am working on some similar methods to Lumley's `biglm` wrapper around Miller's AS274 algorithm, and I can't seem to find a reference for his incremental Huber/White sandwich covariance innovation? The only mention of 'how' it works I can find comes from [this talk](https://faculty.washington.edu/tlumley/tutorials/user-biglm.pdf) (page 31). But I'm looking for more details. I get how to create a "$(p+1)^2 \times (p+1)^2$ matrix of products of x and y", but I'm not sure how this gets me the 'meat' I need for the sandwich? I *could* look at the code, but 1) I'd like to read up more on this implementation anyway, and b) I'm writing a `Python` wrapper for AS274, and the default license for most scientific `Python` code is not GPL (usually BSD-3), so I'd need to implement the sandwich from 'scratch' so to speak, in order to avoid `R`'s default GPL license.

Any thoughts, references, other talks given by Lumley? Frankly, an explanation of his implementation would also do nicely, as then I could probably figure out the required code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a reference, because it's too minor to be publishable. I've put the computations [here](http://notstatschat.tumblr.com/post/145438762776/computing-the-simplest-sandwich-estimator).  It's just algebra: multiplying out the middle term of the sandwich estimator and collecting terms so that the sums involving $\beta$ are outside the sums over rows of the data, instead of inside.